# Check if parameter value is null or not inside query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my query I am getting records based on `RoleId` and `LocationId`, some times the user may not pass location in that case I want to remove that filter and get information from all locations.

Currently I am doing this way

```
if(loc > 0)
{
    var myResult = (from x in CSDB.Allocations
                   join s in CSDB.Managers
                   on x.ManagerId equals s.Id
                   Where x.RoleId == 2 && s.LocationId == loc
                   select new
                   {
                    x.name,
                    x.Date
                   }).ToList();
}
else
{
    var myResult = (from x in CSDB.Allocations
                   join s in CSDB.Managers
                   on x.ManagerId equals s.Id
                   Where x.RoleId == 2 
                   select new
                   {
                    x.name,
                    x.Date
                   }).ToList();
}
```

I am seeing if I can check if `loc` is null or not inside the query instead of using if else.

Comment: But you're testing `loc` against `0`, not against `null`.

Comment: that is actually a int variable..

Comment: @JasperKent a comparison with null always retuns false, so `null > 0` (and `null < 0` as well) returns false

Comment: @ChrᴉzsaysreinstateMonica Only if `loc` is a nullable value type, which is not clear here. But even if it is, is seems like deliberate obfuscation.

Comment: Apart from the discussion about null or zero, I think your method is way more efficient than checking the value of loc again and again, once for every row, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Where x.RoleId == 2 && (loc == null || s.LocationId == loc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do smth like this.

```
Where x.RoleId == 2 && (loc?.Equals(s.LocationId) ?? true)
```

If `loc` just `int` I would prefer to use a little bit changed [@Salah Akbari answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986050/2946329):

```
Where x.RoleId == 2 && (loc == 0 || s.LocationId == loc)
```

Comment: if ``loc`` is null, the query will not give all locations that have ``RoleID`` equals ``2``

Answer (score 0):

Simply extract your managers and filter them if needed. That way you can as well easily apply more filters and code readability isn't hurt.

```
var managers = CSDB.Managers.AsQueryable();

if(loc > 0)
    managers = managers.Where(man => man.LocationId == loc);

var myResult = from allocation in CSDB.Allocations
               join manager in managers on allocation.ManagerId equals manager.Id
               where allocation.RoleId == 2
               select new
               {
                allocation.name,
                allocation.Date
               };
```